# MySQL COUNT on Tomorrow's Date based on CURDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MYSQL COUNT` Status that is working great by counting records greater than `CURDATE`.  How do I specify this query to ONLY count tomorrow based on `CURDATE` for the column specified?

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as total_count 
FROM HTG_ScheduleRequest 
WHERE (ScheduleDateCurrent > CURDATE()) 
    AND JobStatus = '3' 
GROUP BY SSR
```

Comment: What is the data type of `ScheduleDateCurrent`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is DATE type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" way is:

```
WHERE date(ScheduleDateCurrent) = date_add(CURDATE(), interval 1 day) AND JobStatus = '3'
```

The better way is:

```
WHERE JobStatus = '3' AND
      ScheduleDateCurrent >= date_add(CURDATE(), interval 1 day) AND
      ScheduleDateCurrent < date_add(CURDATE(), interval 2 day)
```

The reason this is better is because it can take advantage of an index on `JobStatus, ScheduleDateCurrent`, if one is available.

Comment: I like the better way, this actually helped me solve another query issue within that page that was slow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following query would do the trick

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as total_count 
FROM HTG_ScheduleRequest 
WHERE (ScheduleDateCurrent BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          AND  DATE_ADD(DATE(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) 
    AND JobStatus = '3' 
GROUP BY SSR
```

Answer (score 1):

To count only the rows having tomorrow's date (and non-NULL `ID`), you could do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as total_count 
FROM HTG_ScheduleRequest 
WHERE (ScheduleDateCurrent = ADDDATE(CURDATE(),1)) 
    AND JobStatus = '3' 
GROUP BY SSR
```